# Enabling SSL for Sendgrid clickthrough links on WPEngine

Tags: reverse-proxy, sendgrid, wpengine

We need the last step completed for Sendgrid to be able to create the SSL.

Steps are:
Using a Proxy

To prepare your account for SSL for click and open tracking using a proxy, please follow the following steps:

```
Prepare a proxy (like a web application, NGINX, or Amazon API Gateway) to take all traffic for mailing.example.com and forward it to http://sendgrid.net or https://sendgrid.net.
Set up the proxy to use HTTP or HTTPS. For HTTPS, provide a valid SSL certificate for mailing.example.com domain.
To forward traffic, set the Host HTTP header to mailing.example.com domain.
Point the CNAME record to your proxy. For example, CNAME mailing.example.com proxy.example.com.
```

In the steps above, mailing.example.com will need to be replaced with your actual link branding, and proxy.example.com will be replaced with your proxy.

WPEngine ref: https://wpengine.com/support/using-a-reverse-proxy-with-wp-engine/

QUESTION: What RULE needs to be created in order to supply it to our host WP Engine?

Thanks for any help you may provide.

Edit:

Tried this server rule in the nginx config:

```
  server {
    server_name mailing.example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
        location / {
        proxy_pass http://sendgrid.net;
        proxy_set_header Host mailing.example.com;
    }
  }
  server {
    server_name mailing.example.com;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://sendgrid.net;
        proxy_set_header Host mailing.example.com;
    }
  }
```

ERROR - When saving the rule to NGINX: nginx-before did not save. Error: server" directive is not allowed here.

Comment: What do you mean what rule? You've linked the documentation that you should follow to implement this. Are you getting errors or unexpected results? What have you tried?

Comment: We have no developer or IT person that can write this (example below) to work on WP Engine. When they applied this "rule" it resulted in error when trying to use a sample rule we found:

Comment: `server {
 server_name mailing.example.com;

    listen 80;
 listen [::]:80;
  
 location / {
     proxy_pass http://sendgrid.net;
     proxy_set_header Host mailing.example.com;
 }   
}

server {
 server_name mailing.example.com;

 listen 443 ssl;
 listen [::]:443 ssl;
    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;
    
 location / {
     proxy_pass https://sendgrid.net;
     proxy_set_header Host mailing.example.com;
 }   
}`

Comment: ERROR - When saving the rule to NGINX: 

nginx-before did not save. Error: `server" directive is not allowed here`

it doesn't like the use of the word "Server" in the rule. Let me try removing that to see if that resolves it. Then:

Comment: Error - `nginx-before did not save. Error: unexpected "{` 

The nginx rule on WP Engine will not work on our servers as it is currently written. We're going to either need to modify this rule, or rewrite it. Since this is a proxy related rule, WP Engine can't be the ones to rewrite it.

Comment: I would recommend that you hire a developer or IT person to do this for you. Remote debugging nginx config over Stack Overflow without knowing or understanding the rest of your config is not the best way to get something done in a way that you can rely on. Maybe WP-engine has some suggested freelancers you could work with to achieve this and have someone on call for further changes if needed.